# Excel copy and pbpaste

Tags: terminal, ms-office, copy-paste

When I copy from Excel (Microsoft® Excel for Mac Version 16.11.1 (180319)) and paste into the terminal (Versian 2.8 (400)) via `pbpaste` I often (but not always) get weird chars at the end.

Why is that? Can it be avoided?

I'm on macOS High Sierra Version 10.13.13, my `locale` is:

```
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: Can you please give us some examples of what output you are getting, it will help us diagnose the issue. Thanks!

Comment: And also what the input/content in Excel is, please

Comment: @patrix I can't share the Excel conten (confidential). All looks good, and then about 26k of this got added after the last char: 뾻뮻뾻뮻뾻뮻뾻뮻뾻뮻뾻뮻뾻뮻뾻뮻뾻뮻뾻뮻뾻뮻뾻뮻뾻뮻뾻뮻뾻뮻뾻뮻뾻뮻뾻뮻뾻뮻뾻뮻뾻뮻뾻뮻뾻뮻뾻뮻뾻뮻뾻뮻뾻뮻뾻뮻뾻뮻뾻뮻뾻뮻뾻뮻뾻뮻뾻뮻뾻뮻뾻뮻T뾻뮻뾻뮻뾻뮻뾻뮻뾻뮻뾻뮻뾻뮻뾻뮻뾻뮻뾻뮻뾻뮻뾻뮻뾻뮻뾻뮻뾻뮻뾻뮻뾻뮻뾻뮻뾻뮻뾻뮻뾻뮻뾻뮻뾻뮻뾻뮻뾻뮻뾻뮻뾻뮻뾻뮻뾻뮻뾻뮻뾻뮻뾻뮻뾻뮻뾻뮻뾻뮻뾻뮻뾻뮻뾻뮻뾻뮻뾻뮻뾻뮻뾻뮻뾻뮻뾻뮻뾻뮻뾻뮻뾻뮻뾻뮻뾻뮻뾻뮻뾻뮻뾻뮻뾻뮻뾻뮻뾻뮻뾻뮻뾻뮻뾻뮻뾻뮻뾻뮻뾻뮻뾻뮻뾻뮻뾻뮻뾻뮻뾻뮻뾻뮻뾻뮻

Comment: Are there any *invisible* spaces you're not aware of after the last character in your Excel file?

Comment: @monomeeth - not that I'm aware of. The cell is formatted as "Accounting" though, with some right margin.

Comment: @simone Totally appreciate the confidentiality of your Excel content (I work with classified data all the time). I'm just wondering whether you could create a small sample of your data (but with the data changed so as not to breach confidentiality) and test again to see if you still have the issue? If the issue persists, would you then be able to share *that* version for me to test at my end?